# What's causing the WebDriverException "Caused by: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Session was terminated due to TIMEOUT

Tags: java, testing, selenium-webdriver, grid, automated-tests

The problem I have; I get some timeout :

```
Caused by: org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridException: Session [88131a70-87d7-4cf7-b7a5-f01de85f6012] was terminated due to TIMEOUT.
```

For those tests, the tests start and are very long. That's ok that they are long because the test waits for a third party to receive a response. So, I don't want to have the grid to terminate the test.

I have a selenium Grid, with 1 hub and 2 nodes.
Nodes configuration are as follow :

```
"port": 5554,
"hubPort": 4444,
"hubHost": "xxx.yyy.zzzz",
"nodePolling": 5000,
"registerCycle": 1800000,
"register": true,
"cleanUpCycle": 5000,
"timeout": 12000,
"browserTimeout": 12000,
"nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 12000,
"maxSession": 4
```

For the Hub part, no config file is set.
I'm currently running selenium server 2.53.0.
As I can see, my timeout, `browserTimeout` and `nodeStatusCheckTimeout` are more than enough to wait for the completion of the test before the connection is dropped.
The problem occurs about 5 minutes after the test is launched.

Comment: The logs from the node or driver should tell you why the timeout occurred.  It usually happens when implicit waits are used or when a resource in the page is falling to load or when the driver failed to respond due to a bug.

Comment: We have no implicit wait in our framework. Logs on nodes are not telling much; exception driven by the grid. No clues. Timeout suggest to adjust a property but we don't know which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium grid serves all your selenium requests, as a result you'll have to increase the -jettyMaxThreads. The default is 200 (selenium v3.11). You might run more load than what your jetty engine can handle.